# will everything automatically close in this code if there is an exception

Tags: vb.net

three questions please

1) If there is an exception in the try below will the  request stream automatically close as it is in a `using`

2)`do I even need the requestStream.Close() and requestStream.Dispose() as it is in a using?`

3) do I need to close the System.Net.FtpWebRequest?

```
Try


    Dim rqst As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(System.Net.WebRequest.Create("ftp://1.com/text.txt"), System.Net.FtpWebRequest)
    rqst.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("useb", "pass")
    rqst.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile

    'Throw New ApplicationException("Exception Occured")
    Dim fle() As Byte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:\test.txt")

    Using requestStream As Stream = rqst.GetRequestStream()


        requestStream.Write(fle, 0, fle.Length)
        requestStream.Close() 'do I need this?
        requestStream.Dispose() 'do I need this ?

    End Using

Catch ex As Exception

    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString())

End Try
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you dont need if you are using `using`. As `using` itself is used to dispose of. Also the reason for the "using" statement is to ensure that the object is always disposed correctly, and it doesn't require explicit code to ensure that this happens.

Dispose method is called immediately when control flow exits the using block.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  If the exception occurs while executing code inside the using statement, the stream will be disposed before it goes to the Catch block.